# Xamarin Android - Write to file - access denied

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm getting path to save a video .mp4 file by using the following code in **PCL** project, which return "**/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/**":

```
 #if __ANDROID__
   var dir = Android.OS.Environment
   .GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
   var publicPath= dir.AbsolutePath;
   var newFilepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(publicPath, fileName); 
   video.path = newFilepath;
 #endif
```

I've added permissions to **Android.Manifest** as bellow:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this function will get the .mp4 file from internet and save to the path:

```
 public void downloadVideo(VideoInfor video, bool isRetried)
    {
        if (!video.downloadUrl.Contains(HLS) && !video.downloadUrl.Contains(HLS_1))
        {
            string filepath = video.path;

            if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(video.downloadUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) && !video.downloadUrl.Contains("https://v.vnecdn.net/vnexpress/video/video_default.mp4"))
            {
                video.downloadUrl = video.downloadUrl.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading url:  " + video.downloadUrl);
                try
                {
                    if (!video.downloadUrl.Contains(".m3u8"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Downloading.....");

                        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(video.downloadUrl);
                        if (isRetried)
                        {
                            request.Timeout = 120000;
                        }
                        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                        {
                            using (Stream source = response.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (FileStream target = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                                {
                                    var buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    bool cancel = false;
                                    int bytes;
                                    int copiedBytes = 0;

                                    while (!cancel && (bytes = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                    {
                                        target.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

                                        copiedBytes += bytes;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception download url = " + video.downloadUrl);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception download url Exception = " + ex.ToString());
                    if (!isRetried)
                    {
                        downloadVideo(video, true);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When the program running into "t**arget.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);**" I get the exception "Access to the path is denied", so anyone plesae tell me why is this error happening?

I already tried **Plugin.permissions**:

```
 Dictionary<Permission, PermissionStatus> results = 
 await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
 PermissionStatus status = results[Permission.Storage];
```

but I got "**status = Permission.Unknow**"

I already tried to save the video to a private path that only my application can access following code, which return "**/data/user/0/com.companyname.VideoDownloader/files/**":

```
 var dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
     video.path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, filename);
```

And downloadVideo function can be able to write all the bytes data into the path with no error, but I cannot see any files when browse to that path.

Here is my SDK configuration:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```

Comment: Can you mention the target sdk version used?

Comment: @GauravKP: here it is: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

Comment: Looks like the directory where you are trying may not exist, try to save in an existing directory, or create the directory before saving the file

Comment: @GauravKP: I already call  new FileInfo(video.path).Directory.Create(); before call the downloadVideo

Comment: Since your target sdk is 25, have you [requested permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions)? You could refer to this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) for how to do it in xamarin.

Comment: @ Billy Liu - MSFT : you should put your comment as an answer, it is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your target sdk is 25, you have to [request permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions). You could refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) for how to do it in xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I had all of the above things about permission enabled in my project and it still wouldn't let me write to files, just read them.

My solution: you have to use `Path.Combine` in the `File.WriteAllText(..)` even though you pass a string variable in the `File.WriteAllText(path)`, you still need to write it as `File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path))`